# Cache selector in object (jquery)

Tags: jquery

i've a problem... What am I doing wrong?

I want to use a selector previously saved in a variable. The idea is to use it within a function in an object.

```
var escribir = {
    obj:$('#cont'),
    algo: function(i) { 
        escribir.obj.html(i++);
        setTimeout('escribir.algo('+i+')',1000);
    }
}

$(document).ready(
    function(){
    escribir.algo(0);
    }
);

....
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: the problem is...  obj:$('#cont') and escribir.obj.html(i++); not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be better if you made use of closures in better form.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var escribir = {
        obj : $('#cont'),
        algo_counter : 0,
        algo : function () {
            escribir.obj.html(escribir.algo_counter++);
            setTimeout(escribir.algo, 1000);
        }
    };

    // optionally:
    // escribir.algo_counter = 10;

    escribir.algo();

}
```

This way, you're not using `setTimeout`'s `eval` version.

Answer (score 1):

```
var escribir = {
    obj : $('#cont'),
    algo : function (i) {
           |
           V
        escribir.obj.html(i++);
        setTimeout(function() { escribir.algo(i) }, 1000); // Don't use `eval`
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/sQdST/

Comment: Passing in a function **call** to `setTimeout` won't work. If not the `eval` version (which is, yeah, evil) you'll have to pass in a function **reference**. So you'll have to wrap that in a lambda : `setTimeout(function () { escribir.algo(i); }, 1000);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your **obj** is the member of **escribir**, so you need to change it to `escribir.obj`:

```
var escribir = {
    obj:$('#cont'),
    algo: function(i) { 
        escribir.obj.html(i++); // without escribir.obj you will get reference error, otherwise you have a variable name obj.
        setTimeout('escribir.algo('+i+')',1000);
    }
}
```